# Performance of different method of calling JavaScript/jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Is there any performance difference between:

Example 1:

```
$(window).on('resize', abc);

function abc(){
  //some abc code
}
```

Example 2:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  //some abc code
});
```

If yes, what are the pros and cons of each?

If no, which is the preferred practice?

Comment: Performance difference in running that code *once* on page load, or performance difference for the event handling? As with your other question, unless you have code in a hot loop, execution speed differences are irrelevant.

Comment: First variant is slower, because it must first check function, than call it. But you will see mostly no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Example 1:

```
$(window).on('resize', abc);

function abc(){
  //some abc code
}
```

In this **abc()** function can be used on window resize and we can use that function on any other event. But working of this function is slow as compared to  **Example 2**

Example 2:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  //some abc code
});
```

**Example 2** works faster than **Example 1**. This function works only on **Window resize.**

If you want to use **abc()** function more than 1 Event then **Example 1 is good** otherwise **Example 2 is good.**

Comment: _But working of this function is slow as compared to Example 2_, Can you explain further?

Comment: @MathewJibin   Yes. As it will first call function abc() and search for that function. So it is slower than Example 2